7-section LC filter design
In the book "The Art of Electronics" there is this circuit:

The text states:
We designed the filter with a weird input and output impedance (378 ohm) to take
advantage of standard value tunable inductors
Can you explain to me what that means?
Perhaps it means that at the resonance freq. the total impedance of the 7 LC filters is exactly 378 ohms as the resistance R1?

In filter design, you can scale inductor/capacitor ratio by choosing the termination resistance. In this design, perhaps the goal was fitting to standard-value 100uH inductors which had an adjusting slug that can tune inductance over a small range.
A Chebyshev design applet gave the following results for various termination resistance. Notice that you can choose the termination resistance so that it scales all the inductors and capacitors. Apparently, the designer had found inductors near the 100uH ballpark that were tune-able. The design parameters were identical for these three filters, only changing termination resistance (50 ohms, 378 ohms, 600 ohms):

0.1 dB ripple
frequency 934 kHz (which gives -3dB point of 1.0 MHz)


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

